# How should a material design dialog box be animated?

Tags: material-design

I'm writing an application with a material design layout, but can't find any guidelines on how to animate dialog boxes onto the screen.

This suggests that the box should just "ping" into existence, but that seems to go against the ethos of the design, with its animations and tactile feel.

Does anyone have more information on what the correct course of action is?

Here are the specs for dialog boxes, by the way: http://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-specs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look at existing Google apps, and it appears that the dialog box fades in at full size. The transition is pretty quick, like 0.25 seconds.

If you go into Developer Options and change *Window animation scale* to 10x, it will slow things down enough for you to see it clearly.

I chose Google Calendar > New Event, then select the different fields to see the dialog appear.

Here's a screen recording I did that shows the animation.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbU5yRhSbKg